# Blank page on the web server with Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, path, webserver, codeigniter-4

I uploaded my project to the web server, Following the security recommendations, I placed the CodeIgniter 4 files in the server's non-public directory:
`/home/user/codeigniter`

and And in the public directory:
`/home/user/public_html`

And here is my path:
`$pathsPath = FCPATH. '../codeigniter/app/Config/Paths.php';`

I placed all files properly like;

```
|__ public_html (or your domain root folder)
| |assets
| |index.php
| |.htaccess
|
|__ codeigniter
|__ app
|__ system
|__ writable
|__ .env
```

But i always receive a blank page.
Could you help me to handle this problem please

And error.log is:

```
RITICAL - 2020-10-14 06:12:09 --> ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time
#0 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->errorHandler(2, 'ini_set(): Head...', '/home/catideko/...', 101, Array)
```

Comment: Did you give your writable folder the correct permissions? That would be my first guess. If those folders are with the correct permissions then you should be able to check the logs in the writable/logs folder for more information about the specific error. If that folder is empty you can check your server error logs, if its apache check the logs there, if its nginx try those. Finally if there's no errors on any of those, check if your server has error logging turned on.

Comment: Did you have any errors in error.log?

Comment: Also I see that you're sending the .env file to your webserver, that is not a good practice, the application should have the production settings in its code and the respective config files. The .env file is used for developers to override those settings without changing anything in the code. Shouldn't be used in production.

Comment: Yea here is my firs line of error.log `RITICAL - 2020-10-14 06:12:09 --> ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time
#0 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->errorHandler(2, 'ini_set(): Head...', '/home/catideko/...', 101, Array)`

Comment: It looks like you have something fishy going on with your sessions. Post the code where you load the session library and how you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. The sourche of problem is about "zlib_output_compression" in my host. It should be "off" position. On cpanel after changing the position as "off" everything go well.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong `$pathsPath = FCPATH. '../codeigniter/app/Config/Paths.php';`
You can not use `FCPATH` and `..` together like that, you have to provide full path, like `$pathsPath = '/home/user/codeigniter/app/Config/Paths.php';`

Also make sure the path `/home/user/codeigniter` is accessible by php, either you need to include that path in your `php.ini` or set in your index.php

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/home/user/codeigniter');
```

and than confirm if your path is included

```
echo get_include_path();
```

and than confirm if you have updated all paths correctly by following [official guidelines](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html)

once all setup, make sure your writeable folders has write permissions set. and your App.php includes

```
public $sessionSavePath          = WRITEPATH . 'session';
```

Although above setup will work, I suggest you to stick with default composer installation and paths

```
composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter project-root
```

This will insure seamless updates when CI4 is upgraded, to make your app more secure restrict access in your writeable folder, like with nginx/apache you can restrict which type of files could be opened from those folders.